# design of nested BCH codes

Tags: coding-theory

I want to design four **systematic** binary BCH codes B1,B2,B3,B4 with the following properties. I am using the notation (n,k,d) where n is the codeword length, k is the dimension and d is the minimum distance.

B1 = BCH(118,108,4)

B2 = BCH(118,99,6)

B3 = BCH(118,90,8)

B4 = BCH(118,81,12)

In addition, the following must be satisfied:

**B4 ⊂ B3 ⊂ B2 ⊂ B1**, that is B4 is a subcode of B3, B3 is a subcode of B2 and so on.

Shortening, extending or any other combination of modifications to known BCH codes is allowed. I know that designing such codes should be possible because I am trying to recreate the work presented in a publication.

My own approach was to start with BCH(511,502), then shorten it by 394 bits to get BCH(117,108) and then extend it by a parity bit to get B1 = BCH(118,108). Then I take BCH(511,493) and shorten and extend again to get B2 = BCH(118,99) and so on for B3 and B4. The problem is then I don't know if that guarantees B4 ⊂ B3 ⊂ B2 ⊂ B1. I can't do a brute force search to determine if the codewords are nested like I want, that seems intractable.

Edit: As an afterthought, if I had the generator matrices for the codes, would that make the task of determining if they are nested any easier?

Comment: Dilip's answer is correct. But this massive shortening makes me wonder. Why don't you shorten BCH-codes of length 127 (+ extension) instead? You get a little bit larger codes that way? BCH(118,110,4), BCH(118,103,6), BCH(1118,96,8) etc.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. What you need to do is construct the length-$511$ cyclic BCH codes with generator polynomials $M_1(x)$, $M_1(x)M_3(x)$, $M_1(x)M_3(x)M_5(x)$ and $M_1(x)M_3(x)M_5(x)M_7(x)$ where $M_i(x)$ denotes the minimal polynomial of $\alpha^i$ where $\alpha$ denotes your favorite primitive element of GF$(2^9)$ or $\mathbb F_{2^9}$. The construction guarantees the subset property that you are looking for in the primitive (length-$511$) BCH codes thus constructed, and all that needs to be done is to make sure than when you are shortening the codes to length $118$, you are throwing away the same information bits in all four cases, thus guaranteeing that the subset property carries over to the shortened codes as well.